# What planes can have one wing? GTA V (PS4)

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I'm working to create a [mini series](https://youtu.be/oVjZKb_Pmnk) for my Youtube channel which includes removing landing gear, landing on building's, and flying with one wing. As no-one else on the internet seems to have this query and having limited time to test myself, I must ask for help here. What I need to know is (mainly) what planes can have their wings broken off without exploding immediately afterwards (besra for example). Additional information such as what planes can have there landing gear taken off is also very helpfull to me. For those that want to know what I am doing with no wing's is flying an aircraft and hitting stunts like flying through the windfarms.

Comment: I don't remember if any planes had issue with landing gear coming off.. It's just much harder to land, but still doable

Comment: Yes, I think I prove that it is still doable by landing on the maze bank with two wheels. But what I meant was if I hit my wheel in a larger jet would it come off easy or would it explode?

Comment: Wheels usually pop right off

Comment: Thanks for the information. Testing it on the commercial plane in a second.